# error: 'str' object does not support item assignment in python

Tags: python, geopy

I am trying to geocode address using geopy by using some code downloaded from github.
but the error the code is that the str obj doesn't support item assignment in `geocode_addresses address_dict["error"] = ""`?
why do I get that error. below is the code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    csv_file = 'nr-fixedNew.csv'
    with open(csv_file, 'rb') as csvfile:
        for row in csvfile.readlines():
            df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
            address = df.ADDRESS
            geocoded = geocode_addresses(address)
            write_csv(output_file, geocoded)


    def geocode_addresses(address_dicts):
        geocoder = geocoders.GoogleV3()
        for address_dict in address_dicts:
            address_dict["error"] = ""
            try:
                time.sleep(1)
                address, (lat, lon) = geocoder.geocode(address_dict["fulladdress"])
                address_dict["fulladdress"] = address
                address_dict["latitude"] = lat
                address_dict["longitude"] = lon
            except ValueError as e:
                address_dict["error"] = e
        return address_dicts
```

dataset example

```
SEX,PROGRAMME,ADDRESS
M,2,"J6855, JALAN LMBAH KESANG 1/1-3,77378 MERLIMAU, MELAKA";
```

Comment: Please provide more detail, specifically, what *is* `address_dict`. Presumably it's a `dict`, but the error suggests otherwise.

Comment: `address_dict` appears to be a  `str` -- which means you need to look in your code where `geocode_addresses` is called to figure out why it is an iterable of strings.

Comment: can you provide an example dataset ?

Comment: @mgilson edited the question

Comment: Just because you *call* a variable `address_dict` does not mean it contains a dictionary. If `address_dicts` is itself a dictionary, then you are actually iterating over its *keys* which in this case appear to be strings.

Comment: @mgilson I don't think so - it's not complaining about the attempt to subscript using a string. I'm guessing it's something that supports `__getitem__` but not `__setitem__`.

Comment: @AmiTavory -- No.  Give it a try:  `s = 'foo'; s['bar'] = ''` raises a `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: @mgilson Interesting - you're right. What's surprising is that just `s['bar']` gives a different error. I don't understand it, I must say.

Comment: @AmiTavory -- `s['bar']` calls `__getitem__`, `s['bar'] = ''` calls `__setitem__`.  Since `str` are immutable, `__setitem__` will always fail no matter what you pass in so there is no reason to bother checking the type.  `__getitem__` will succeed for `int` or `long` or appropriate `slice`, so some type-checking needs to be done and can be used to help format the error message.

Comment: @mgilson Many thanks for the interesting explanation. I was just about to ask this as a question. I wish I could somehow upvote + accept your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it looks like `address`/`df.ADDRESS` in the snippet below:

```
    address = df.ADDRESS
    geocoded = geocode_addresses(address)
```

`address` is not a list of dicts like you're expecting it to be:

```
for address_dict in address_dicts:
    address_dict["error"] = ""
```

---

after testing your code, here's what `address_dicts` is:

```
(<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

which is basically a (`pandas`) list of strings:

```
(Pdb) address_dicts
0    J6855, JALAN LMBAH KESANG 1/1-3,77378 MERLIMAU...
Name: ADDRESS, dtype: object
(Pdb) address_dicts[0]
'J6855, JALAN LMBAH KESANG 1/1-3,77378 MERLIMAU, MELAKA;'
```

so your issue is related to how you're parsing the CSV file.

---

And tbh, I don't really understand what you're trying to do here:

```
with open(csv_file, 'rb') as csvfile:
    for row in csvfile.readlines():
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
```

so you're opening the file, then you iterate over the file, and for each line you're parsing the file as a csv ?!

---

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    csv_file = 'nr-fixedNew.csv'
    with open(csv_file, 'rb') as csvfile:
            df = pd.read_csv(csv_file).to_dict() ### here you convert to dict
            address = df['ADDRESS']
            geocoded = geocode_addresses(address)
            write_csv(output_file, geocoded)
```

and then you need to rethink the way you're parsing the values. Don't hesitate to call pdb or add printouts.

Comment: im trying open the file, read every line and get retrieve the address field to pass to geocode_addresses. im not familiar with python, i didnt know that both line is for opening the file

Comment: the original code is originally for an input file that only have the address in there.

Comment: i get new error. geocode_addresses
    address_dict["error"] = ""
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object does not support item assignment

Comment: that means you f*cked up again, and your `address_dict` is full of `int`s. When you have an issue, lookup the line it is throwing the exception from, and try to add a `print()` of the object that's guilty (like `print(address_dict)` in your case). Also, you can launch a debugger by adding `import pdb; pdb.set_trace() # XXX BREAKPOINT` just before the line that breaks to open a command line python to debug.

Comment: also, if you have more questions about your code, create a new question! Because questions are free, and I'm not always around, so you'll give a chance for others to help you out.